# Change the Content of the Page When User Click On A Different Option On DropDown List

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, listbox, dropdown

I got a drop down list. User upon selecting different value, I should get the option text of the option user has selected from the dropdown list, then go find the data from the database and display the relevant content on the webpage. If user change the option again, I should go retrieve different data based on option text selected and display the different content on the webpage.

How could I accomplish this? Anyone has any idea to keep me started? I researched online but couldn't find anything useful.

This is my codes:

**ASPX file:**

```
<asp:Dropdownlist ID="SelectionDropDownList" 
                  runat="server" Width="136px" 
                  EnableViewState="True" 
                  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
</asp:Dropdownlist>
```

**CS file:**

```
//how the dropdown list is being populated out. Dropdown list is being populated out from what the user has selected from a listbox.
public void BindSomething()
{
    DateTime choosenDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spretrieve, conn))
        {
            //Lost to hold the values
            List<DateTime> listCopy = new List<DateTime>();
            DateTime dt;
            string values = String.Join(", ", ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Text));
            if (values.Contains("Select All"))
            {
                //Loop through each items in listbox and then add it to list
                foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
                {
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(li.Text, out dt))
                    {
                        listCopy.Add(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Loop through each items in listbox and then add it to list
                foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
                {
                    //check if item is selected
                    if (li.Selected == true)
                    {
                        //add items to list
                        listCopy.Add(DateTime.Parse(li.Text));
                    }
                }
            }

            //compare and sort so that the latest date comes on top
            listCopy.Sort((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));
            //clear the items in dropdownlist
            SelectionDropDownList.Items.Clear();
            //set the datasource to dropdownlist
            SelectionDropDownList.DataSource = listCopy;
            //set the dateformatstring in dropdownlist
            SelectionDropDownList.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}";
            //Bind the dropdownlist
            SelectionDropDownList.DataBind();
        }
```

Appreciate if someone can help me on this, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#SelectionDropDownList').change(function(){
  //here you can add code for whatever you want to show   
});
});
```

I hope this will help you.